# Merge elements at the same position starting with the integer queue

Tags: python-3.x

Given two queues, one integer queue and another character queue, write a python program to merge them to form a single queue.  Follow the below rules for merging:

Merge elements at the same position starting with the integer queue.
If one of the queues has more elements than the other, add all the additional elements at the end of the output queue.

Note : max_size of the merged queue should be the sum of the size of both the queues.

For example,

```
Input -- queue1: 3,6,8     queue2: b,y,u,t,r,o
Output -- 3,b,6,y,8,u,t,r,o
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: There's no question here. What are we suppose to answer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want to achieve. Your question was not well formulated though.

```
q1 = [3, 6, 8]
q2 = ['b', 'y', 'u', 't', 'r', '0']

q1_max = len(q1)
q2_max = len(q2)

dif = q2_max - q1_max

i = 0
res_out = ''
while i < q1_max:
    res_out += str(q1[i]) + ',' + q2[i] + ','
    i += 1

while dif < q2_max:
    res_out += q2[dif] + ','
    dif += 1

print(res_out)
```